# Cypher where clause fails for multiple paths

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using the below cypher i am try to return nodes where :

They must be connected by a particular relationship and the value of a property in relationship must be greater than 1.

```
match (n:Title)-[rel:REQUIRES_SKILL]->(x:Skill)
where rel.frequency > 1
return n, rel, x
```

This doesn't works, if between 2 nodes there are multiple relationships. It returns every relationship, even the one having frequency value equal to 1.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the results you get when you use "Rows"?

Comment: Added an picture of result, what do you mean by "Rows" ?

Comment: Referring to the table or text views, I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try turning `Connect result nodes` off. Else there are all possible relationships displayed between the resulting nodes.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works this way, but even earlier i saw that when its checked although you get all nodes in neo browser but in "Table" section you get only valid results. You know anything about why it is so ?

Comment: Yes. The result is always the right one! If you for example only get nodes as result they are still connected with each other when its checked. So the check box only changes what you see not the actual result

Comment: Yes. To be precise, what this option does is, after getting the results of your query (for the row/text results), it issues another query to get all relationships between the returned nodes, and uses that for display with the graph result view.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, it means my query was correct but i was incorrectly looking at result.

Comment: Correct :) but this also a helpful feature in other cases!

Comment: @NirmalVatsyayan Could you please mark this answer as correct if you are happy with the answer

Comment: Yes of course, sorry i should have done that earlier.